# Can we solve the shortest-path with a space filling curve?

Tags: shortest-path, space-filling-curve

I wonder if we can solve the shortest-path with a space filling curve or is there a better solution? How good would be the approximation compared to an exact solver? The graph doesn't need to satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: Do you have some constraints/goals that make A* or Dijkstra's algorithm not applicable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A* with good heuristic function is generally the best solution (in terms of speed and finding shortest path).

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve with space-filling curve. I suppose it could give you interesting path in areas where costs are equal.

Comment: Note that the heuristic must be an admissible heuristic in order to get the actual shortest-path. This is not always easy to do.